# how to access unicode-encoded characters beyond the utf8 range, e.g., \symbol{"110367}?

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontspec, unicode

Some OpenType fonts provide several of their most intriguing glyphs in slots that cannot be accessed in Unicode (which is limited to 0x10FFFF). An example: the `EB Garamond` font family provides glyphs called `f.short` and `f_f.short` in slots `0x110367` and `0x110360`, respectively. (In case you're curious: these glyphs are variants of the glyphs `f` and `ff` -- the latter being a ligature -- which have short "arms", i.e., arms which protrude much less to the right than the arms of the "regular" glyphs `f` and `ff` do.)

Aside: I obtained the slot numbers `0x110367` and `0x110360` by opening the otf file in FontForge.

If I try to access, say, `f.short` naively via either `\symbol{"110367}` or `\symbol{1114983}`, I get the following error message:

```
! Bad character code (1114983)
```

Short of lobbying font designers to stop placing glyphs such as `f.short` and `ff.short` in slots that are beyond the Unicode range, how might one access these glyphs?

Just in case it isn't clear: I'm interested in LuaLaTeX-based solutions. If the solution is compatible with the `fontspec` package, the better.

---

A full MWE (to be compiled with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\symbol{"110367} % "f.short" 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, Unicode is limited to `0x10FFFF` and UTF8 has nothing to do with this, being just a way to access Unicode code points with multibyte combinations.

Comment: I looked in the lua of ebgaramond and there is nothing at 1114983, f_f.short e.g. is at `983904` and `\symbol{983904}` worked fine.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I realize I may have been using unicode terminology a bit (too!) loosely. The question should maybe be rephrased as: "Since `0x110367` is beyond the UTF8 range, how does one access the glyph located in that slot, given that `\symbol{"110367}` throws an error message?"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. I'm afraid I don't quite understand the phrase "the lua of ebgaramond". :-( Is there a specific file I should be looking for?

Comment: The log-file shows that a `ebgaramond12-regular.luc` is loaded. In the same location there is a readable `ebgaramond12-regular.lua`.

Comment: @Mico UTF8 might easily be extended to use up to seven bytes (now it uses up to four), addressing many more code points than Unicode does. It is *Unicode* which is currently limited to `0x10FFFF`. Both XeTeX and LuaTeX convert UTF8 input into Unicode before tokenization.

Comment: @Mico In my `ebgaramond12-regular.lua` file, `f.short` and `f_f.short` are listed at code points 983911 (`0xF0367`) and 983904 (`0xF0360`) respectively. With a standard preamble, the input `f \char983911\ ff \char983904` outputs [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH0dD.png).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. The last character in EB Garamond 12 Regular is in slot `0xF0477`, whereas `f.short` and `f_f.short` are in slots `0xF0367` and `0xF0360` respectively. Indeed,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

f \symbol{"F0367} ff \symbol{"F0360}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Here are the relevant excerpts from `ebgaramond12-regular.lua`:

```
  [983904]={
   ["boundingbox"]=449,
   ["index"]=2822,
   ["name"]="f_f.short",
   ["unicode"]={ 102, 102 },
   ["width"]=579,
  },

  [983911]={
   ["boundingbox"]={ 24, -3, 332, 706 },
   ["index"]=2829,
   ["name"]="f.short",
   ["unicode"]=102,
   ["width"]=317,
  },

   ["f.short"]=983911,

   ["f_f.short"]=983904,
```

The same input compiled with XeLaTeX does not show the “short” glyphs. One can get the glyphs with XeLaTeX by addressing them by name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

f \XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"f.short"\ %
ff \XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"f_f.short"

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I had obtained the slot numbers `0x110367` and `0x110360` by opening the opentype font file in FontForge and looking for glyphs with `.short` in their names. Apparently, `luaotfload` maps these too-large numbers into smaller numbers that can be accessed via `\symbol` and `\char`!